# Merging shelved changlist into branch

Tags: linux, version-control, perforce, perforce-integrate, perforce-branch-spec

A colleague of mine has a shelved change list (`CL#12345`) which includes edits and new (added) files. The files all live within:

```
//software/my_luggage/main/...
```

I would like to `unshelve` these changes, and apply them to the branch located at:

```
//software/my_luggage/beta/...
```

I tried just generating and manually applying a patch via:

```
p4 describe -S 12345 > ~/tmp.patch
```

However, this has two problems:

1. The patch needs to be converted to a common Unix diff format, similar to the output of `p4 diff -du` (I have a script for that).
2. The output of the `p4 describe` operation doesn't contain the content in the new/added files.

Is there a simply way to `p4 unshelve` a shelved changelist and modify the destination where the shelf would be "applied", or do I have to manually copy and re-add the files, manually patch individual files, etc? **I'd prefer to do it via the command line, and not the `P4V` GUI, if possible**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a branch spec with:

```
Branch: luggage_beta
View:
    //software/my_luggage/main/... //software/my_luggage/beta/...
```

Run:

```
p4 unshelve -b luggage_beta -s 12345
p4 resolve
```

You will need a 2013.1 or later Perforce server:

```
Major new functionality in 2013.1

    #538913 (Bug #36686) **
        Shelved changes may now be unshelved into different branches
        or related streams via 'p4 unshelve -b' and 'p4 unshelve -S'.  
        See 'p4 help unshelve'.
```